# How to detect if first token of Scanner.next() is an Integer of a String?

Tags: java

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.next(); //How to detects if the first token is an int; i.e (Integer.valueOf(scan) 
//will not throw InputMismatchException
```

I have overloaded methods

```
  void name(String name){
  System.out.println(name)
  }
  void age(int age){
  System.out.println(age)
  }

  void printAgeOrName(){
  System.out.println("Enter name or age");
  String data = scan.next();
 *if(first token of date is int){
  age(Integer.valueOf(date));
  }else{
  name(data);
  }
` }
```

scan.hastNextInt() only works for when more than one token is entered.
I am yet to be aquinted with regex

Comment: if (scan.hasNextInt())

Comment: I would encourage you to check [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for the class you are trying to use; it may provide you an answer more quickly than asking on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i;
while (scan.hasNext()) {
  if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    i = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("int: " + i);
  //do whatever
  }
 //do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing, thanks to @João Gatto code.

```
 void printAgeOrName(){
      System.out.println("Enter name or age");
      String data = null;
    try{
      data = scan.next();
      age(Integer.valueOf(date)); // will throw NumberFormatException if data is not an integer
    }catch (NumberFormatException n){  // catch and assume data is a string
      name(data);
      }
` }
```

Answer (score 0):

The nextInt method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

Print "This is not an integer" when user put other than integer

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
try {
  System.out.println("Please input an integer");
  int usrInput=sc.nextInt();
  ...
} catch(InputMismatchException exception) {

  System.out.println("This is not an integer");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use exception handling to detect a condition when the API provides you means to check: `sc.hasNextInt()`.

Comment: Want to handle an Integer and String at the same time. Since name(String name) and age(int age) are in if-else condition.

Comment: I think @joao just gave me an Idea. Catch an exception, then process the iteration of if-else from the catch block

Comment: No need for exception handling: `if (sc.hasNextInt()) { int value = sc.nextInt(); } else if (sc.hasNext()) { String next = sc.next(); }`.

Comment: @Nexima360 I think Andy is right. I thought you were having issues in catch the exception. I read the question and the first line and I thought that. I am starting to use StackOverflow, I need to be more careful answering the  questions. Sorry about that, my mistake.

Comment: @JoãoGatto Your suggestion paved way to it already. See third code as my update, its based on your solution